# How to use the "to_date" function in Oracle with a variable as parameter?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, to-date

I have a stored procedure that contains the following:

```
V_DATACONVERTIDA varchar2(100) := TO_DATE('27/10/1994 23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS');
```

It works fine, but the problem is I gotta make that date a variable. So I created

```
V_DATAEXPIRACAO VARCHAR2(100) := p__formdata;
```

being *p__formdata* (varchar2) a parameter from the SP.

When I made that change, though, I got the following error:

**ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected**

Comment: It seems you are assigning date output to VARCHAR2.

Comment: I know, but (I dont know how or why) but in the first line of code I posted I'm doing the same thing and it works. :(

Comment: I switched from varchar2(100) to date and it threw me the same error

Comment: Can you post more of the stored procedure? I don't think there's enough information to go on here - for example, we don't know the data type of `p__formdata`.

Comment: it's varchar2 as well, I don't understand why it says it expects a numeric value when everything is supposed to be string (or varchar)

Answer (score 1):

> " I don't understand why it says it expects a numeric value when
>   everything is supposed to be string (or varchar)"

Well clearly everything *isn't* a string.  Oracle hurls the ORA-01858 error we attempt to cast a string to a date but with wrong format mask; for instance this example passes a character month but specifies a numeric month in the mask: `to_date('08-APR-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')` .

So, if you're getting that error your program isn't doing what you think it is.  But only you can see the whole source, so only you can figure out where the bug lies.